# I want to do texture mapping on three js, but the texture appears black

Tags: three.js

I want to map texture to cube geometry in three js. However, applying texture mapping changes the object to black.

```
      var cubeGeometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 30, 1);
      const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();


      const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: loader.load("./wall.jpg", undefined, undefined, function(err) {
              alert('Error');
          }),
      });
      var cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry1, cubeMaterial);
      cube1.castShadow = true; 
      cube1.position.set(0,15,-50); 
      scene.add(cube1);
```

A './wall.jpg' exists within that project.  When run that code, an Error message appears. Why is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture = textureLoader.load('yourTex.jpg');

// (or that) const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "yourTex.jpg" );

const cubeGeometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 30, 1);
const cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry1, cubeMaterial);
scene.add(cube1);
```

BTW, usually when I had that issue, was problem with load texture in some ways, wrong path, etc.